# i3wm significant lag vs. normal ubuntu gnome session

Tags: upgrade, i3-wm

I use i3wm for a couple of years now on Ubuntu. Never had an issue like this one before. I just upgraded to 22.10, but after the update, while in i3wm, I have the following issues:

1. Whenever I open an application, the screen will temporarily tear, showing other (or previous) applications on some parts of the screen.
2. In a terminal there is a lot of keyboard input lag.
3. Emacs is particularly bad, the input lag is horrendous, at one point even looked like the laptop froze for a bit.
4. Actually, the lag is especially bad on any Desktop where I have Vim OR Emacs open. So bad that the laptop actually freezes for about 5 seconds before I can do anything.

**5. New Information:** I discovered that, on a clean boot directly into i3wm, this lag will happen. If however I log into a normal Ubuntu Gnome session first, then log out of that and back into gnome, then suddenly this lag disappears.

This **did not** happen on 22.04 (i3wm) and if I log into a normal gnome session this is also not a problem.

Also, I should point out that I did try compton, since some people mention that this might be the cause on other forums... This did not resolve the issue.

Anyone knows what the issue is here?

```
$ neofetch
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               andre@andre-framework 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           --------------------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 22.10 x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: Laptop (12th Gen Intel Core) A4 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.19.0-23-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 22 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 1690 (dpkg), 23 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 5.2.2 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 2256x1504 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: i3 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   Theme: Yaru [GTK3] 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Icons: Yaru [GTK3] 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Terminal: gnome-terminal 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    CPU: 12th Gen Intel i5-1240P (16) @ 4.400GHz 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     GPU: Intel Alder Lake-P 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      Memory: 2029MiB / 15708MiB
```

PS: *Do not tell me to use gnome session instead*, non-tiling window managers became very cumbersome to me by now and it slows my work down significantly. I would much rather format and reinstall 22.04 and i3wm, than use any non-tiling wm at this stage.

Comment: I advise you to do a reinstall, however without erasing your partitions: that preserves user configuration and data while refreshing system files (select "Something else" in the live installer. If that still does not solve the issue, a fresh install will be warranted - actually, in case of i3wm, I do not know what you miss out remaining on the 22.04 LTS release.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Sometimes logging out and logging back in resolves the issue for me. Please let us know if you've found a persistent solution.

Comment: @EserAygün I found a solution. I installed Regolith linux. It's just another ubuntu variant, but uses i3wm. I now have no more lags. I think there is something with how GTK and Gnome is configured on ubuntu that caused issues with i3wm. Regolith seems to do something right in that regard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this issue had something to do with default i3wm running on top of Ubuntu.

So I decided to do use [Regolith](https://regolith-desktop.com/) linux instead. This is a distro that packages i3wm on top of ubuntu.

No more periodic freezes and lags.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, input lag in i3 but not in gnome on ubuntu 22.10.

The solution for me was to upgrade to linux kernel 6.0 or downgrade to <5.19.